# Sharing in Android in Facebook SDK. Two apps post messages, but only one remains

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk

I have two apps at my Facebook developer's console. I [read the guide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/share) and created a Facebook dialog to share some text in each app.

But when I post a message from one app and post something else from the other a bit later, the second message replaces the first one. I tried posting from two devices: the first message from my phone and the second message from my tablet. The second message keeps replacing the first one.

What is it? A bug in Facebook SDK or some anti-spam policy?
I used [Facebook SDK v. 3.18](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The Easy Share Action](http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/shareaction.html) works fine. I posted two messages, one after another, and nothing disappeared.